# Updating a value in a YAML file and dump it

Tags: python, yaml

I have a YAML file, specified as follows:

```yaml
%YAML 1.2
---

source: 'NULL'
target: 'NULL'
```

The file is read as a dictionary:

```
import yaml
with open('path/to/file.yml', 'r+') as file:
    value = yaml.safe_load((file))
    print(value)
```

This prints
`{'source': 'NULL', 'target': 'NULL'}`

Now, just as an example, I have a variable `new_v = 23`, and I update the value of the source key in the YAML file, how do dump the newly created dict?

Comment: You need to re-write the file with the changed YAML output, as in `yaml.dump()`.

Comment: Research this in two steps: 1. how do you change the value of a key in a dictionary; and 2. how do you save a dictionary to a YAML file (likely using the same library you loaded it with). Neither should be particularly complex, but if you have a more specific problem with either step please [edit] to clarify

Comment: I think I didn't formulate it very well. I can update a value in a dict, but the dumping is the actual problem, where I couldn't find a clear answer. The documentation is a bit unclear to me : https://pyyaml.org/wiki/PyYAMLDocumentation

Comment: The recommeded extension for YAML files has been `.yaml` since at least September 2006. PyYAML parses a subset of the YAML 1.1 specification. It should warn if a document is parsed that has a higher minor version number than it supports, but it fails to do so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to take a look [here](https://www.pythonforbeginners.com/basics/convert-python-dictionary-to-yaml).

In short, updating a YAML file is the same as writing to any other type of file. Load the file content as a dictionary, update the values as you see fit, then overwrite the entire file, in this case using the `dump` function from PYYAML to print in YAML format.

```py
import yaml

with open('path/to/file.yml', 'r') as file:
    value = yaml.safe_load(file)
    
value['source'] = 'test'
value['new_v'] = 23
    
with open('path/to/file.yml', 'w') as file:
    yaml.dump(value, file)
```

```
new_v: 23
source: test
target: 'NULL'
```

If the order of the keys is relevant to you, consider using an [OrderedDict](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict), which keeps the entries in insertion order.

Comment: Thank you! In the meantime I also found what I needed:

```with open('path/to/file.yml', 'w') as file:  yaml.dump(value, file)```

Comment: PyYAML has a streaming interface. By not providing its stream argument, you let it stream into a buffer, return that buffer as a string and then stream out the string to a file. That is inefficient in time and space, you should always use `yaml.dump(value, file)` instead, and that is shorter in code as well.

Comment: @Anthon Edited accordingly. :)